# CheckBoxList en un asp:panel, usando ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtende?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Necesito hacer que un CheckBox sea Visible mientras estan seleccionando elementos, el checkbox se encuentra dentro de un asp:Panel. El código es el Siguiente:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panela" CssClass="form-control grfp-checkbox-panel">Razón Social</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender BehaviorID="dropDownExtender1" ID="DropDownExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="panela" DropDownControlID="CheckBoxList1">
</ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="grfp-checkbox-items">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<script runat="server">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Quizás este video te puede ayudar

[How to Add CheckBox Inside GridView asp.net c#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLYpgORPtBY)